# Get LI to be 25% width

Tags: html, css, format

I am trying to get

http://meyers.ipalaces.org/sitemap/

to look like

http://meyers.ipalaces.org/sitemap2/.

The first link is using a more standard approach thats easier to program for where the 0 level (baseurl) is in it's own `UL` with it's own `LI`. The problem is that all the sub-levels are now located in the primary `LI` and I need to make the `LI` to be `width: 25%` for the formatting and background to look right.

I am looking for any ideas anyone can offer, I am OK with wrapping the primary `LI` with something.

Edit:

Let me clarify the problem to you, I need the style/design that the `LI` has but I cannot resize the `LI`. If I make the base `LI` any smaller, every `UL` and `LI` inside it will be 25% of that, essentially 25% of 25%.

Perhaps there is a better way to do it without percentage widths? or maybe there is a way to make the element look exactly like the `LI` should but it's really a `DIV`

Comment: Have you looked into Child Selectors or Adjacent sibling selectors? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "quick fix" available.

First, remove this:

```
#testnav ul {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Then, on `#testnav li`, set the `width` to `25%`.

Oh dear, that doesn't look very good (as you realised), does it?

Fortunately, there's an easy way to fix it. Add:

```
#level--1 {
    width: 400%
}
```

This will counteract setting `width: 25%` on the `li`, and in effect sets it back to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

`.sitemap { width:600px; }`

or give it a range you're comfortable with

`.sitemap { min-width:400px; max-width:600px; }`

Then the children at 25% (as you have them) should match your goal example.

Comment: Am I missing something? Just setting the .sitemap width should fix the width of the "home" toplevel LI?

Comment: The answer you chose does the same thing (leaves the white bg intact tho). I was trying to work with elements without "test" in them.

Comment: I am still confused, even if I reverse the `#level--1 { width: 400% }` and then apply `.sitemap { width: 600px; }` I get this: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/7996/a0832512f0c9405fb4914f7.png

Comment: I am too. I used Firebug and then (because of your comment) downloaded your page (http://meyers.ipalaces.org/sitemap/) - in both scenarios changing .sitemap's width was all it took: http://img691.imageshack.us/i/meyers.png/ (btw: width ended up being 500px before it really started to match your desired effects).